# Google Cloud Platform LAMP setup Laravel 5.4

Tags: google-cloud-platform, laravel-5.4, google-compute-engine, lamp

Looking for help on server problem. I have followed the following steps to set up LAMP on the VM

https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-lamp

I put my Laravel 5.4 website onto the VM, configure the `.env` for the following:

`APP_URL=website_external_IP`

But when I access the website by inserting the website_external_IP on my browser, it returns the following image.

Sorry for being noob of server problems but please let me know what else information should I provide for you to figure out the cause of it. Thank you!

[image: qwe]

## 1 EDIT:

In response to John Hanley's suggested site. I further made the following edits on the apache conf:

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel_project.conf
sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel_project.conf
```

and there vim the `laravel_project.conf` as followings

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
Listen 8080
 
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName laravel.dev
    ServerAlias www.laravel.dev
    DocumentRoot /home/user/projects/laravel_project/public
     
    <Directory /home/user/projects/laravel_project/public/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
     
    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

then

`sudo vim /etc/hosts`

and add the following line:

`127.0.0.1   laravel.dev`

then disabled the original conf settings and enable for my site:

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
sudo a2ensite laravel_project.conf
```

Without having the full understanding of the new edits procedures, accessing the page with IP returns the following error:

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Answer (score 0):

Your Apache web server has directory browsing enabled. Also you do not have a default page present (or enabled) therefore you server is serving up the directory listing.

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Remove the word `Indexes` from this part of your configuration:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        ...
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks John. I removed `Indexes` and restarted Apache. Now the page turns to `You don't have permission to access / on this server.` I also followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others to change the ownership of the folders and files.

Comment: You don't have a default page. What is your home page filename? If you look in the file `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf` under `<IfModule mod_dir.c> ` you will see the list of default filenames that Apache will search for. I would look at the file `readme.md` for details on how to configure your setup.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I went into readme.md but doesn't seem to show any clues. In Laravel I dont see index.php at the root and i think all the frontend files are in `/resources/views`. Under development, I would run `php artisan serve` in CLI so that I can directly access the website by putting `localhost:8000` into my browser without any further work done. So I guess if it works under development without the index.php at root then there should be an easier way to configure in production too.

Comment: Maybe this article will help: https://phpraxis.wordpress.com/2016/08/02/steps-for-configuring-laravel-on-apache-http-server/

Comment: John Hanley~ thank you for your helps all the way long. I have attempted as the site suggested but effort seems to still be in vain.

Comment: Please have a look at my edit in the post and see what i am missing at your convenience~ thank you very much